# Add 2 row counts together in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am adapting something and I need to add 2 row counts together in mysql. So far I have

```
<? 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 ='2' ");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM Table2 WHERE Field2 ='6' ");
$num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

$num_rows3 = ($num_rows + $num_rows2)

echo "$num_rows3";
?>
```

I can echo either $num_rows OR $num_rows2 fine but I need to do the calculation then echo $num_rows3.

I am probably doing something stupid here but I do not know mysql at all so I am trying to learn.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah I thought as much! I need to add the 2 counts together.

Comment: lol sorry I removed my comment as I thought I had it wrong but yes try $num_rows3 = $num_rows + $num_rows2;

Comment: Just noticed I was missing the ;    That was it! Whoops!

Comment: Yep never noticed that myself :/

Comment: Thanks for the help though, you made me realise it!

Comment: You should really consider using mysql_real_escape_string if "2" and "6" are user-supplied, and `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...` is a lot better performing than `SELECT * FROM ...`.

Comment: Mark this as solved :).

Answer (score 3):

You could also have one single query for both counts:

```
SELECT count(t1.id), count(t2.id)
FROM (SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 ='2') t1,
      (SELECT id FROM Table2 WHERE Field2 ='6') t2
```

Also note that you are missing a `;` when summing the counts.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a suggestion even though you got your answer.
If you want to add those into ONE MYSQLI query you could use this:

```
SELECT sum(cnt) from 
(SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM T1 WHERE Field1=2 union all 
 SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM T2 WHERE Field2=6) a
```

I just don't see the point in fetching all data in `SELECT * FROM` Where all you do is `mysql_num_rows($result)`

Hope this helps, and maybe improves your code.

Good Luck!

Here is just a demo IN SQLFiddle, so you can see this in action:

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e80d7/16)**

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the ; after the calculation!!

Answer (score 1):

Using only one query and counting before add, a possible code is

```
<? 

   $query  = "SELECT c1 + c2 FROM ";
   $query .= "(SELECT count(Field1) c1 FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 ='2') t1,";
   $query .= "(SELECT count(Field2) c2 FROM Table2 WHERE Field2 ='6') t2";

   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $value  = mysql_num_rows($result);

   echo "$value";
?>
```